# Why do I get run time fatal error - Range width expression must be positive - for my up counter design?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level, digital-design, active-hdl

I am trying to design a 17-bit ripple up counter using a positive edge triggered d flip flop in my design.  Here is my code:

```
`timescale 1us/ 1ns 

module upcounter (clk, pr, clr, out);
    input wire clk;
    input wire pr;
    input wire clr;
    output wire [16:0] out;
    
    wire [16:0] fb;
    wire [16:0] i_wire;
    
    //const int n = 16;
    genvar i;
    
    //wire and1, and2;

    generate
    for (i = 0; i<17; i++) begin
        //int j = i;
        if (i == 0)begin
            dff d[i] (.clk(clk),.pr_b(pr),.clr_b(clr),.d(fb[i]),.q_b(fb[i]),.q(i_wire[i]));
        end else begin 
            dff d[i] (.clk(fb[i-1]),.pr_b(pr),.clr_b(clr),.d(fb[i]),.q_b(fb[i]),.q(i_wire[i]));
        end
        assign out[i] = i_wire[i];
    end
    endgenerate
endmodule
```

The code compiles without any error, but while initializing simulation it throws up a runtime fatal error saying `Range width expression must be positive`, it indicates the error occurs in the following line:

```
 dff d[i] (.clk(clk),.pr_b(pr),.clr_b(clr),.d(fb[i]),.q_b(fb[i]),.q(i_wire[i]));
```

How can I solve this error?

I'm using active hdl as the EDA.

I have tried using `generate` and `endgenerate` block.

Answer (score 1):

VCS generates this compile error:

```
Error-[ZONVS] Zero or negative value for size
Line 19
upcounter, "genblk1[0].i"
  Zero or negative value for size is not allowed.
  Value: 0
  Please fix the size value as a positive number.
```

When i=0, `dff d[i]` resolves to `dff d[0]`, which the compiler does not like.

In that line, you can use `d0` instead of `d[i]`:

```
        dff d0 (.clk(clk),.pr_b(pr),.clr_b(clr),.d(fb[i]),.q_b(fb[i]),.q(i_wire[i]));
```

That gets past the compile error.  However, you end up with a lot more than 17 `dff` instances, which you probably don't want.  For example, when i=4, `d[i]` resolves to `d[4]` which is an array of 4 instances.

You likely just want to use `dff d` on both lines.  This gives you 17 `dff` instances.